# getting NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

when I make this request from my template:

```
<a href="{{ route('getprodpage', ['id' => $product->id, 'entity' => 'incentive']) }}">
```

This is my routes.php

```
Route::get('getprodpage/{id}/{entity?}', [
    'as' => 'getprodpage', 'uses' => 'ProductController@countProductClicks'
]);
```

What is wrong with this?

EDIT

This is how I'm doing with nested resource:

routes.php

```
Route::get('product/{id}/entity/{entity}', [
    'as' => 'getprodpage', 'uses' => 'ProductController@countProductClicks'
]);
```

Blade template request:

```
<a href="{{ route('getprodpage', ['id' => $product->id, 'entity' => 'incentive']) }}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to make route 'getprodpage/{id}/{entity?}'

Try with:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers
Example:

```
Route::get('products/{id}', ['as' => 'ShowProduct', 'uses' => 'ProductController@show']);

Route::get('products/{id}/categories/{catId}', ['as' => 'ShowProductCategory', 'uses' => 'ProductCategoryController@show']);
```

Then in your CategoryController@show method you get two variables:

```
show($productId, $categoryId){

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But I'm still getting the same problem. I update the question with the nested route. Can you check please?

Answer (score 0):

It happen with cache,

use command

```
php artisan route:clear
```